# XMPPMessage time

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework

I'am working with **XMPPFramework** for iOS and I need to show message's date and time.
After some searching I think that I should use `XMPPAutoTime` module, but I didn't find some examples.

I used in stream setup:

```
xmppAutoTime = [[XMPPAutoTime alloc] initWithDispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[xmppAutoTime activate:self.xmppStream];
```

My sending message method looks like:

```
NSXMLElement *message = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];
[message addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"chat"];
[message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:to];

[message addChild:[XMPPTime timeElement]];

NSXMLElement *body = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"body"];
[body setStringValue:text];
[message addChild:body];
```

And my XML looks like:

```
<message type="chat" to="toJID">
    <time xmlns="urn:xmpp:time">
        <tzo>+03:00</tzo>
        <utc>2014-12-30T15:24:22Z</utc>
    </time>
    <body>message text</body>
</message>
```

So as you can see I have time in place and it is correct. The question is how I can use it for `XMPPMessage`

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on XMPP too and I'm glad you had this question, as I didn't know how to add time to the messages I send.

Anyway, I'm not sure if there's an easier or a more correct way of doing it, but I use this:

```
[[message elementForName:@"time"] elementForName:@"utc"]
```

inside the `didReceiveMessage` delegate method to extract the time from the XML.